# Value at risk in dollars vs. log returns

Tags: value-at-risk

I have a quick question about this remark in Tsay's book "Analysis of Financial Time Series" (3rd edition).

[image]

He says that
$$ \text{dollar VaR} = \text{Value} \times \text{log return VaR} $$
and that
$$ \text{Value} \times [\exp(\text{log return VaR}) - 1] $$
is an approximation to that.

Based on how quantiles transform, it seems to me that it should be the other way around!

Eq (7.1) for completeness

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. What he calls the approximation is the correct amount, the other is an approximation.